# How to reopen window after closing other one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I work on qml-based application.

Environment:

- Windows 10 64bit
- Python3.7
- PyQt5
- Qt 5.13.1
- Build & Run: Desktop Qt 5.13.1 MSVC2015 64bit

I'd like to have the following behaviour:

- Initially, there is shown Login window.
- After getting access token the Login page closes and General
  window opens.
- After closing the    General window Login window opens again.
- After closing the Login window (literally, if I have no access token after closing the Login window) my program finishes.

Now I have the following issue after closing Login window without access token (login.res_token == ""):

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
The process was ended forcefully.
...\Python\Python37\python.exe crashed.
```

A piece of main.py:

```
def init_app():
    app_login = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    manager = ComponentCacheManager(engine)
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("componentCache", manager)

    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    qml_file = os.path.join(current_path, 'ui/LoginPage.qml')
    engine.load(qml_file)

    login = Login()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("login", login)

    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

    win.show()

    app_login.exec_()

    if(login.res_token != ""):
        main_app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
        engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

        manager = ComponentCacheManager(engine)
        context = engine.rootContext()
        context.setContextProperty("componentCache", manager)

        current_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        qml_file = os.path.join(current_path, 'ui/GeneralPage.qml')
        engine.load(qml_file)

        engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("access_token", login.res_token)

        win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

        win.show()
        main_app.exec_()
        init_app()
    else:
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_app()
```

However, if I code in another way (without recursion), this action works correctly. For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_login = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    manager = ComponentCacheManager(engine)
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("componentCache", manager)

    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    qml_file = os.path.join(current_path, 'ui/LoginPage.qml')
    engine.load(qml_file)

    login = Login()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("login", login)

    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

    win.show()

    app_login.exec_()

    if(login.res_token != ""):
        main_app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
        engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

        manager = ComponentCacheManager(engine)
        context = engine.rootContext()
        context.setContextProperty("componentCache", manager)

        current_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        qml_file = os.path.join(current_path, 'ui/GeneralPage.qml')
        engine.load(qml_file)

        engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("access_token", login.res_token)

        win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

        win.show()
        main_app.exec_()
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

But here I don't reopen Login window after closing General window.

If I write something like that, the program crashes after closing General window with the same error:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while(True):
        app_login = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
        engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

        manager = ComponentCacheManager(engine)
        context = engine.rootContext()
        context.setContextProperty("componentCache", manager)

        current_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        qml_file = os.path.join(current_path, 'ui/LoginPage.qml')
        engine.load(qml_file)

        login = Login()
        engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("login", login)

        win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

        win.show()

        app_login.exec_()

        if(login.res_token != ""):
            main_app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
            engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

            manager = ComponentCacheManager(engine)
            context = engine.rootContext()
            context.setContextProperty("componentCache", manager)

            current_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
            qml_file = os.path.join(current_path, 'ui/GeneralPage.qml')
            engine.load(qml_file)

            engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("access_token", login.res_token)

            win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

            win.show()
            main_app.exec_()
        else:
            break
    sys.exit()
```

How will it be better to resolve this problem?

Comment: There is a part that is confusing to me, you say: *After closing the Login window (literally, if I have no access token after closing the Login window) my program finishes.*, What happens if you still have the token?

Comment: @eyllanesc, when I create a new object **Login()**, its attribute **self.res_login** initially equals to "". This attribute will be changed only after authorization and at the same time Login window closes.

Comment: mmmm, it seems to me that all your solutions use structure programming instead of rethinking it to use OOP where you can use the same object. From what I understand you, you can only enter "General Window" if you have the token, if you do not have it, you will not enter it, if after entering "General Window" you close it then the token will be deleted, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc , yes, you are. If after entering "General Window" I close it then the token will be deleted and "Login Window" will open again to allow another user to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is to use the signals to notify the changes and in the logical part to change the page

```py
import os

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml


class AuthenticationManager(QtCore.QObject):
    login_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    logout_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._token = ""

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(str, constant=True)
    def token(self):
        return self._token

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str, result=bool)
    def login(self, username, password):
        self._token = self._get_token(username, password)
        if self.token:
            self.login_signal.emit()
            return True
        return False

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def logout(self):
        self._token = ""
        self.logout_signal.emit()

    def _get_token(self, username, password):
        "emulate token"
        if username == "user" and password == "pass":
            return "Token"
        return ""


class WindowManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._current_page = ""

        self._engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()

        self._authentication = AuthenticationManager()
        self._authentication.login_signal.connect(self.on_login_signal)
        self._authentication.logout_signal.connect(self.on_logout_signal)

        self._engine.rootContext().setContextProperty(
            "authentication", self._authentication
        )

    def init(self):
        self.on_logout_signal()

    def on_login_signal(self):
        self.current_page = "ui/GeneralPage.qml"

    def on_logout_signal(self):
        self.current_page = "ui/LoginPage.qml"

    @property
    def current_page(self):
        return self._current_page

    @current_page.setter
    def current_page(self, page):
        self._current_page = page
        current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        qml_file = os.path.join(current_dir, self.current_page)
        self._engine.load(qml_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = WindowManager()
    manager.init()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**LoginPage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13 

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Login Page"

    Row{
        TextField {
            id: username
            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter name")
        }
        TextField {
            id: password
            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter password")
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }
        Button{
            text: "Login"
            onClicked: {
                if(authentication.login(username.text, password.text)){
                    console.log("token:", authentication.token)
                    root.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GeneralPage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13 

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "General Page"
    Button{
        text: "Logout"
        onClicked: close()
    }
    onClosing: authentication.logout()
}
```